# When I update products : error url_rewrite Magento2

Tags: php, url-rewriting, magento2

I deleted the category and product url_rewrite from the Magento database to update everything via a script.
The problem is that when I run the script I get this error message after a few upgraded products:

[image]

Is this due to my removing the old url_rewrite?

Comment: Looks like it. Have you tried regenerating the rewrites?

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate url_rewrite.

The terms rewrite and redirect are often used interchangeably, but refer to slightly different processes. A URL rewrite changes the way a URL appears in the browser. A URL redirect updates the URL that is stored on the server. A URL redirect can be either temporary or permanent. Your store uses URL rewrites and redirects to make it easy for you to change the URL key of a product, category, or page and preserve existing links.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but how can i regenerate the url_rewrite? I had downloaded via composer a script which allows to do it for the products but it did not work